# Motion of parametric lines on a surface

Tags: differential-geometry

A curve $  X (u,v)$ inhabiting  $ \mathbb R^2 $ embedded in $ \mathbb R^3 $ rotates on a surface induced by linear combination change of its arguments as:

$$ (u,v)  \rightarrow ( \alpha u + \beta v , \alpha u  - \beta v  ) $$

Is this correct? If so, by what amount  do parametric lines rotate or shift?

EDIT1:

A simple example with 3D images of parametric lines on a surface:

$$ f(u,v)= (\sin u + \sin v, \cos u + \cos v , u + v) \, $$
$$ f(u+v,u-v)= \sin (u + v) + \sin (u-v) ,\cos(u + v) + \cos (u - v),\,2 u) $$
$$ = ( 2\sin u \cos v , 2\cos u \cos v ,2 u) $$

In case they are asymptotic lines( cross/vertical) and geodesics (diagonal) lines they can be interchanged this way, at middle they are superposed.

[image: f(u,v) f( u+v, u-v)]

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the question.

Comment: Is it more clear?  I imagined the migration of curves of catenoid or helicoid $ f(u,v)$ to $ f(u+v,u-v)$ geodesic to asymptotic and vice- versa.

Comment: No, it still makes no sense. You're talking about parametrized surfaces, not curves inhabiting $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: Surfaces are built up of lines and together they make up the scene.